# Show Table in a View - Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop a plugin for Eclipse. I follow tutorials online and I have done a plugin with sample perspective and a sample views.

Now the view show this:

```java
public Object[] getElements(Object parent) 
{
    return new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
}
```

Instead of string I need to insert a table. I follow another tutorial to create a TreeTable, but I have no idea how to put this table Tree into my plugin's view.

This is the code of TreeTable:

```java
public class TreeTableCreation 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
    column1.setText("Column 1");
    column1.setWidth(200);
    TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.CENTER);
    column2.setText("Column 2");
    column2.setWidth(200);
    TreeColumn column3 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.RIGHT);
    column3.setText("Column 3");
    column3.setWidth(200);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
      item.setText(new String[] { "item " + i, "abc", "defghi" });
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        TreeItem subItem = new TreeItem(item, SWT.NONE);
        subItem.setText(new String[] { "subitem " + j, "jklmnop", "qrs" });
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
          TreeItem subsubItem = new TreeItem(subItem, SWT.NONE);
          subsubItem.setText(new String[] { "subsubitem " + k, "tuv", "wxyz" });
        }
      }
    }
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking. What exactly do you want in this view?

Comment: Hello greg-449,

I'm sorry for my bad english.

I need to insert a table in a specific view of my plugin, show in the bottom tabs of eclipse (as console, etc).

Now I have the code that show me an array of string into this view, and another code show me a table in one pop-up.

Have you got idea how to merge them?

Thank you
Roberto

Comment: Can you provide your part code ? I guess the method getElements() comes from your contentprovider class so you also have a class that extends viewpart...

Answer (score 0):

Your view should have a `createPartControl(Composite parent)` method inherited from `ViewPart`. Put your tree table creation code there and use the `parent` parameter as the tree's parent (instead of `shell` in your code).